# MongoDB super-admin authenticates fine but still gets unauthorized query errors?

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I have started using MongoDB with authentication. As per the documentation I used the localhost exception to create an admin user with the single role of *userAdminAnyDatabase*.  That all went fine.  When I run the "mongo" client and authorize against the *admin* database after *using* that database I get the number **1** indicating that authorization succeeded.  However, any command I try to execute results in an "unauthorized" error, even trying to show the collections in the admin database I just authorized against.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?  Currently I am running without authentication until I can get this fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `userAdminAnyDatabase` role (and the `userAdmin` role that it is an extension of) simply gives your user the permission to read and write to the `system.users` collection to administer the users of a database. It doesn't allow the user to read or write to the actual collections of the database. For that, you need to grant the `read` or `readWrite` roles.

See [User Privilege Roles in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) and [Add a User to a Database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the next steps to solve authentication issue:

1. start mongod without authentication enabled and run:
2. create database
3. create user with role
4. create a dummy collection with one document
5. stop/kill mongod
6. start mongod with authentication enabled
7. switch to database created in step 1
8. authenticate on database with user created in step 3

sample commands:

1. `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1`
2. `use educationDb;`
3. `db.createUser({ user : 'readonly', pwd: 'readonly', roles : ['read']})`
4. `db.xyz.insert({"name":"nix.education"})`
5. stop/kill mongod
6. `mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1`
7. `use educationDb;`
8. `db.auth('readonly','readonly')`